# Raspbian-Boot: Failed to start light display

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

For some reason when I booted up my pi today, I'm getting the error 'Failed to start light manager. When I look at the details [image: I see these errors]

Any idea's what is causing this and how I could fix this?

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude reinstall lightdm
```

also

```
sudo aptitude install gdm
```

Every time I reboot I get the blank screen with blinking cursor, in which I press ctrl alt f1 to return to the boot page and see the same error.

I have basically zero linux or raspbian knowledge, any input would be appreciated !!! Thank you.